# Passing JSON data to sebm-google-map-marker and clicking it gives an error

Tags: angular, dictionary

I am getting an error whenever I am clicking on the marker in the below code.

My HTML code is:

```
<sebm-google-map-info-window [maxWidth]="300" [disableAutoPan]="true">
<div class="mapwrapper" *ngFor="let mgd of allMarkersGeoDatas; let j = index">
    <div class="tempSection clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span>{{mgd.count}}</span>
            <span>COUNT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span>{{mgd.typesCount}}</span>
            <span>TYPES</span>
        </div>
    ....
```

Whenever I am passing in JSON data using `{{}}` braces I am getting error in console:

> ERROR TypeError: _co.updateDiv is not a function.

If I remove and hard code the data then no error comes. Does any one any idea, why this error is coming?

Comment: Please explain 'i am passing  json data in using {{}} braces' part. And probably post your component and/or service code if any.

Comment: Sorry for not clearing mentioning my question, actually {{mgd.count}} click giving me the error , when i replace this with hard code value it does not give any error, In Component-- > the code is written                                          clickedMarker(label: string, infoWindow, index: number) {

    if (this.infoWindowOpened === infoWindow)
      return;

    if (this.infoWindowOpened !== null)
      this.infoWindowOpened.close();

    this.infoWindowOpened = infoWindow;

     console.log(`clicked the marker: ${label || index}`)
  }